# Append param if not null in thymeleaf

Tags: html, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have pagination on my page i have some logic on which pagination depends.
I have request param **status** which i need to include in link.

My link:

```
th:href="@{/system(type=${type},page=${page.number - 1},status=${dto.status})}"
```

This code works, but if type null, my link is `/system?type=full$page=1&status=`

So i cant put another params, because last one without value.
Now i need to add one more param, and i have same problem.
So, how to append param to link to `@{}` in Thymeleaf, but only if it **not null**

Comment: There's no problem with a blank param...   Something like this is completely fine: `/system?type=full$page=1&status=&another=&another1=`. There isn't a way in the standard url syntax to do you what you want.

Comment: Can you post complete section of html code please